# Saving user in cookie (headers already sent)

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

I'm creating a multiplayer game in NodeJS using Express and socket.io. Most of the back-end is working, now I'm trying to create the front-end.

Really struggling trying to do the following:

A player opens the website for the first time > create a player in the database and remember the player.
When a player comes again another time we should read the cookie and log the player in again.

My code I have so far:

```
// app.js
app.get('/', function(req, res){

    if(!req.signedCookies.player) {

        var Player = new player();

        Player.on('playerLoaded', function(err, result) {
            if(result) {
                res.cookie('player', Player.id.toString(), { signed: true});
            }
        });

    } else {
        console.log(req.signedCookies.player);
    }

    res.render('index', { title: 'My Game' });

});
```

This line gives a Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

```
res.cookie('player', Player.id.toString(), { signed: true});
```

What's happing at that line:

```
Player.prototype.createPlayer = function () {
    var self = this;

    // we only need a datetime to insert
    connection.query("INSERT INTO players SET `created_at` = now()", function (err, result) {
        process.nextTick(function () {
            if(result) {
                console.log("Successfully created player no. " + result.insertId);

                self.id = result.insertId;

                self.emit('playerLoaded', false, true);
            } else {
                console.log("Trouble inserting a new player");

                self.emit('playerLoaded', true, false);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Then the exact error is happing at this line:

```
self.emit('playerLoaded', false, true);
```

So my questions are:

1. Am I at least going in the right direction in terms of achieving my goal of creating a new player and saving it in a cookie? If not, could someone please help me?
2. If question one is true, why is it giving a error?

Comment: `var Player = new player();` should be `var player = new Player();` :-)

Comment: Just updated answer with fixed code. It should produce no error's anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies is a part of Response Header. They must be set **before** first `write()` call. This is why the error. Set cookie before first `res.write()` or `res.writeHead()` call to fix the error.

This code should work for you.

```
// app.js
app.get('/', function(req, res){

  if(!req.signedCookies.player) {
    var Player = new Player();
    Player.on('playerLoaded', function(err, result) {
      if(result) {
        res.cookie('player', Player.id.toString(), { signed: true});
      }
      res.render('index', { title: 'My Game' });
    });

  } else {
      res.render('index', { title: 'My Game' });
      console.log(req.signedCookies.player);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Am I at least going in the right direction in terms of achieving my goal of creating a new player and saving it in a cookie? If not, could someone please help me?

Not sure about your design. Saving a reference to the player might make it very easy to log in as a different player, depending on how you identify them. It might be safer to have some kind of session management, and then to link a user session with some player.

> If question one is true, why is it giving a error?

Because creating a player is asynchronous - you're hooking on a `playerLoaded` callback. That means `res.render` will be called immediately, before `res.cookie` will - and so the response body is already written (and the headers send) before you try to set the cookie header.

Comment: I want to use sessions also, security is actually very important to me. But I'm kinda having troubles finding a decent resource that teaches me how I should do this.

And indeed, the res.render was being called before the cookie was set, that was giving the error. Fixed that

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my initial problem of the headers sent. Also changed the code to use sessions instead.

```
if(!req.session.player) {
    var Player = new player();

    Player.on('playerLoaded', function(err, result) {
        if(result) {
            req.session.player = Player;
            res.render('index', { title: 'My Game' });
        }
    });
} else {
    console.log(req.session.player);
    res.render('index', { title: 'My Game' });
}
```